# Script de exportacion a Excel

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tengo este script, me gustaría saber como puedo modificar el titulo del archivo que me genera.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('table'); 

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

      tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<a href[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); 
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
 
   
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }  
    else                 
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  

    return (sa);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar `window.open` o meter el contenido en un iframe al estilo Internet Explorer old school, es mejor que asignes el contenido de la tabla a un elemento `a` cuyo atributo `href` declararías como:

```
link.href='data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
```

Si a ese mismo link tú le das un atributo `download` ese atributo provocará que se descargue un archivo con el nombre del atributo:

```
link.download = 'archivo_ejemplo.xls';
```

Te dejo el snippet funcionando

```js
 function fnExcelReport()
{

    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('table'); 

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<a href[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); 
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
 
    var link = document.getElementById('link'),
        nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
    
    link.href='data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);
    link.download=nombre.value;
    link.click();
    
    
}
```

```css
#table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
#table tr,
#table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre" value="miarchivo.xls"/>
<button id="descarga" onclick="fnExcelReport()">Descargar</button>
<a href="#" id="link" style="display:none"></a>
<table id="table"  style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT**

Si tienes problemas con los acentos y la ñ (u otros diacríticos propios de UTF-8) no te sirve usar `encodeURIComponent` puesto que éste [no usa UTF-8 
sino UCS-2](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding). En este caso podrías usar:

```
link.href='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + window.btoa(tab_text);
```

Pero no lo he probado en todos los navegadores. El siguiente snippet me funciona al menos en chrome y firefox:

```js
function fnExcelReport()
{

    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('table'); 

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<a href[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); 
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
 
    var link = document.getElementById('link'),
        nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
    
    link.href='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + window.btoa(tab_text);
    link.download=nombre.value;
    link.click();
    
    
}
```

```css
#table {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
#table tr,
#table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre" value="miarchivo.xls"/>
<button id="descarga" onclick="fnExcelReport()">Descargar</button>
<a href="#" id="link" style="display:none"></a>
<table id="table"  style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Adrián Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Aguiló</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Cáñamo</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Una pregunta como puedo hacer para que me salgan los accentos?? he puesto el meta charset en el head pero nada..@amendiel.

Comment: Edité la respuesta añadiendo una posible solución para UTF-8. No la he probado en todos los navegadores